# how to clear/refresh DataBind in VB.net using visual studio

Tags: vb.net

Here I draw the table data binding using this code :-

```
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
ds.ReadXml(mypath)

VisaDG.DataSource = ds
VisaDG.DataBind()
```

How to clear the VisaDG table after display it?..Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to clear the gridview. The you can do this:

```
VisaDG.DataSource = nothing
VisaDG.DataBind()
```

**EDIT**

Have you tried this?

```
VisaDG.DataSource=New DataSet()
VisaDG.DataBind()
```

Comment: I already do that but nothing happen..it's not clear the table.

Comment: No problem. If you are fine with the answer then you might consider accepting it?